# Weird personal pronoun in genitive

Tags: personal-pronoun

> die Verbindung zwischen den Gedanken und Gefühlen des Dunklen Lords und den **Ihren**

I know that the genitive is German is:

> Ihres, Ihrer, Ihres, Ihrer

So where did **Ihren** come from?? Can someone please breakdown to me how this **den Ihren** was written? My goal is to understand how this is written so that I could use it in the future in different contexts.

Answer (score 5):

*Den Ihren* is the **dative** of *die Ihren* (question: *zwischen **wem**?*)

*Die Ihren* is a nominalized version of the attribute *ihre* in *ihre Gefühle*, hence probably the capitalization (if not capitalized anyway being the polite address form):

> - Zwischen den Gefühlen des Dunklen Lords und ihren Gefühlen.
> - Zwischen seinen Gefühlen [= den Seinen] und den Ihren.

This is just like an adjective would be nominalized, compare:

> - Zwischen den großen und den kleinen Kindern.
> - Zwischen den Großen und den Kleinen.

It works with other possesive attributes as well, they're regularly inclined like adjectives with determiner ('bestimmte Deklination'), e.g. *eure*:

> - *Singular:* der/die/das Eure, des/der/des Euren, dem/der/dem Euren, den Euren/die Eure/das Eure
> - *Plural:* die Euren, der Euren, den Euren, die Euren

Comment: The nominalization of adjectives is nothing new but the nominalization of possessive articles is really weird. I need to practice it. Thank you.